What is the correct translation of the ending of 2 Peter 3:17?
It seems the Greek word used in Peter is only used once in the New Testament for the ending of 2 Peter 3:17  - στηριγμός
“Therefore, dear friends, since you have been forewarned, be on your guard so that you may not be carried away by the error of the lawless and fall from your secure position.” - NIV
“Ye therefore, beloved, seeing ye know these things before, beware lest ye also, being led away with the error of the wicked, fall from your own stedfastness.” - KJV
It seems depending on the translation that one can take a different theological position from the text.
One implies “once saved always saved”, the other that we must keep preserving. What is the correct translation of the word used here without bias attached to it? As it seems very important to understand what Peter was trying to say.
I appreciate the help thanks.

I suggest that the NIV translators wished to head off questions related to "Eternal Security".  And the KJV doesn't deal with the question.  My perspective is that 2 Peter 3:17 says nothing about "Eternal Security" one way or the other.  It is not pro or con.  The topic is not in scope. So, it's wrong headed to build a doctrinal position on this verse.  But, (I think, obviously) that needs some explanation.  I certainly don't wish to invalidate the OP's question. Tthe short version is the text points to who Christ is.
2 Peter 3:17 is the closing part of an Inclusio, the beginning of which is 2 Peter 1:12
Here they are side-by-side (NASB20):

Therefore, I will always be ready to remind you of these things, even though you already know them and have been established in the truth which is present with you.


You therefore, beloved, knowing this beforehand, be on your guard so that you are not carried away by the error of unscrupulous people and lose your own firm commitment, 18 but grow in the grace and knowledge of our Lord and Savior Jesus Christ.

Notice the two bolded phrases which serve as antonyms of each other.  And those phrases point to something that is firmly established.
I've included verse 18 in the second citation because it points back to 2 Peter 1:2-8:

Grace and peace be multiplied to you in the knowledge of God and of Jesus our Lord,
...
For if these qualities are yours and are increasing, they do not make you useless nor unproductive in the true knowledge of our Lord Jesus Christ.

So, this letter sized Inclusio brackets a lengthy monologue about the dangers of false prophetic information about what it means to be "the lord Jesus Christ".  The letter points readers to the "knowledge of Christ."
So, Peter is closing out the topic of the entire letter.  That topic relates to what it means to "know the Lord Jesus Christ."  And, most importantly, this knowledge of the Lord Jesus Christ is comprised of behavior that is productive for the Christ.  One can't escape the emphasis on action expressed in 2 Peter 1:5-7, and especially considering the word 'unproductive' in verse 8.  In other words, knowledge of the Lord Jesus Christ is not something you circle on a multiple choice test.  It somehow involves action.  The words Peter uses are γνῶσις or ἐπίγνωσις.
This point is important because it means that "knowledge of Christ Jesus" is more than just "believe in him".  It's about adopting his identity as the one who molds who I am.
Recent neuropsychological research suggests two types of knowledge (actually 4): Conceptual Knowledge and Procedural Knowledge.  Conceptual Knowledge aligns quite well with what the Greeks termed "οἶδα" (to know).  γνῶσις (to know) and its cousin ἐπίγνωσις (to relate to and so know) aligns quite well with the meaning of Procedural Knowledge.  The former is knowing which answer to give on a test.  The later is accurately and consistently completing another person's sentences.  You know that person.  This type of knowledge is the knowledge Peter is instructing his readers to grow in.
And the body of the letter is a very stern warning about getting the prophetic word from the wrong people.  Why?  Because having my identity molded by false prophecy is dangerous.  When that happens, we loose the foundation of the truth.
This paints a context within which one needs to interpret 2 Peter 3:17.  In other words, there is the "prophetic word made more sure" (2 Pet. 1:19) that speaks of the Christ, the one seen by Peter (and others) [2 Peter 1:16-18], spoken about by the Prophets [2 Peter 1:19-21], and taught by Paul [2 Peter 3:15-16].  And, testified to by God himself (2 Peter 1:17).  This is the 'steadfastness' referred to and declared to be our very own.
With this, I disagree with Calvin1.  He places 2 Peter 3:17 into a purely hortatory genre, and I don't think you can separate encouragement from a basis in fact.  That's not to say that this verse isn't hortatory, it is.  But, I think it's wrong to split the encouragement of the text from a doctrinal position of the text just because one assumes the text suggests a doctrinal position (which you disagree with).  I don't think it suggests that doctrinal position (so, you can't use the verse in support, either).  It posits that the Christ, and the truth of the Christ--who he is and what he has done--as that which is rock-solid.  The entire epistle of Peter points people to focus on the revelation of Christ Jesus--that's the point of the letter!
What does 2 Peter mean?  It means, Focus on the revelation of Christ Jesus;  He is the one with whom, in whom, we have rock-solid, full assurance; don't believe anyone that says anything contrary to that.
What this means practically speaking is this:  If you believe that your faith secures your salvation, then you aren't believing in the rock-solid foundation to begin with.  You might have faith, but it's not in the right object.  Stepping away from the wrong object does not mean you've lost the right object.  It means you've lost the wrong object, substituting a new wrong object.  Unless, of course, you substitute the right object, which is Christ Jesus, the rock-solid foundation.
Finally, our commitment is to a person who

...knows how to rescue the godly from a trial, and to keep the unrighteous under punishment for the day of judgment (2 Peter 2:9).

Which brings not only a sobering sense of seriousness to the topic, but a place of profound rest.  He knows (οἶδα).  He'll get the right answer on this test.
And a sidebar:  I don't think any translation needs adjusted.  It's more that the phrase,  ἵνα μὴ τῇ τῶν ἀθέσμων πλάνῃ συναπαχθέντες ἐκπέσητε τοῦ ἰδίου στηριγμοῦ, however it's translated, refers to being carried away from a "secure commitment to practiced truth".  It's not referring to being carried away from a "secure position of salvation."  2 Peter is written to believers to encourage them to tenaciously hold to solid doctrine centered on Christ Jesus.
But, thankfully, that underscores the fact that our salvation isn't tied to a perfectly held doctrinal position, either.  Nor even tied to the practice of truth.  If so, then 2 Peter is written purely to unbelievers to scare them into believing, and the whole Eternal Security question goes out the window anyway.  c'est la vie.

1"It seems that the assurance of our salvation stands on slippery ground and hangs suspended as if on a thread, since he warns the faithful to beware that they do not fall from their stedfastness(sic).
What, then, will happen to us if we are exposed to the danger of falling?  I reply that his exhortation and others like it are not made with the purpose of undermining the security of our faith which rests on God, but of correcting the idleness of our flesh." -- Calvin's New Testament Commentaries, Hebrews and I and II Peter, page 368

The two translations are equally valid; they convey the same idea.

One implies “once saved always saved”, the other that we must keep preserving.

It's not clear how anyone that doesn't inject their own personal belief into scripture (eisegesis) would think that there is any implication of "once saved always saved".
Consider the context of the preceding verse and the introduction to the chapter:

3:3 Knowing this first, that there shall come in the last days scoffers, walking after their own lusts,
…
3:16 … they that are unlearned and unstable wrest, as they do also the other scriptures, unto their own destruction.
3:17 Ye therefore, beloved, seeing ye know these things before, beware lest ye also, being led away with the error of the wicked, fall from your own stedfastness.

Clearly the "fall" would be to "destruction", from what is now a stable and well understood position.
Peter is simply pointing out that some people "wrest" (twist, turn awry, pervert) scripture for their own purposes.
But they do so out of ignorance of the truth, whilst Peter's audience is knowledgeable of the truth.
And unlike these other people, whose position is "unstable", their existing knowledge provides them a well established position that they must maintain.

This verse is about falling from "grace" (verse 18)...not 'salvation':
2 Peter 3:18

But grow in grace, and in the knowledge of our Lord and Saviour Jesus Christ. To him be glory both now and for ever. Amen.

It would be fair, and right I believe (1 Cor 2:13), as Peter also mentions Paul's epistles, to further expand on what Peter is referring to regarding the unlearned who "wrest" with scripture (or doctrine).
Ephesians 4:13-16

Till we all come in the unity of the faith, and of the knowledge of the Son of God, unto a perfect man, unto the measure of the stature of the fulness of Christ:
14 That we henceforth be no more children, tossed to and fro, and carried about with every wind of doctrine, by the sleight of men, and cunning craftiness, whereby they lie in wait to deceive;
15 But speaking the truth in love, may grow up into him in all things, which is the head, even Christ:
16 From whom the whole body fitly joined together and compacted by that which every joint supplieth, according to the effectual working in the measure of every part, maketh increase of the body unto the edifying of itself in love.

Both Peter and Paul are referring to believers who begin to fall back on false doctrine.  They "fall from grace" (not salvation) when they begin to forget, or not fully trust in, what it was that saved them to begin with, which was by God's grace through having faith alone.
Galatians 5:4-7

Christ is become of no effect unto you, whosoever of you are justified by the law; ye are fallen from grace.
5 For we through the Spirit wait for the hope of righteousness by faith.
6 For in Jesus Christ neither circumcision availeth any thing, nor uncircumcision; but faith which worketh by love.
7 Ye did run well; who did hinder you that ye should not obey the truth?

Just as Paul is reproving saved believers for disobeying the truth (verse 7 above), Peter also warns his audience to not fall victim to doctrine that is contrary to God's grace.  It is by God's grace through having faith alone that one is "sealed unto the day of redemption" (Eph 2:8-9, Eph 4:30).  However, there could certainly be loss of reward for the believer that has erred in their "obedience to faith" (Acts 6:7, Rom 1:5, Rom 16:26), or in preaching a gospel of a foundation other than that of God's grace and Christ crucified for us.
1 Corinthians 3:11-15

For other foundation can no man lay than that is laid, which is Jesus Christ.
12 Now if any man build upon this foundation gold, silver, precious stones, wood, hay, stubble;
13 Every man's work shall be made manifest: for the day shall declare it, because it shall be revealed by fire; and the fire shall try every man's work of what sort it is.
14 If any man's work abide which he hath built thereupon, he shall receive a reward.
15 If any man's work shall be burned, he shall suffer loss: but he himself shall be saved; yet so as by fire.

Galatians 1:6-9

I marvel that ye are so soon removed from him that called you into the grace of Christ unto another gospel:
7 Which is not another; but there be some that trouble you, and would pervert the gospel of Christ.
8 But though we, or an angel from heaven, preach any other gospel unto you than that which we have preached unto you, let him be accursed.
9 As we said before, so say I now again, if any man preach any other gospel unto you than that ye have received, let him be accursed.


"This verse is about falling from "grace" (verse 18)...not 'salvation'" — Are you saying that there is salvation without grace? How does falling from grace differ from losing salvation?

@RayButterworth If someone falls from grace, they are returning to the attempt of establishing their own righteousness.  A believer does not lose salvation if they do this.  They are allowing Satan's "ministers of righteousness" to keep them from growing any further in God's grace.  No, there is not salvation without God's grace.  All have been gifted God's grace, but not all receive the gift...by faith.

Then, how can one fall from grace without loosing salvation?

@Dottard It is because falling from grace, and losing salvation mean different things.  Question: Do you believe that one is saved (by God's grace) through having faith alone, and without any of our own works of righteousness? Basically, do you believe what Eph 2:8-9, and Eph 4:30 state?  What exactly are you basing your hope for salvation on?

Absolutely!!  I believe in salvation by Christ alone, through grace alone, by faith alone, as revealed in the scripture alone, to the glory of God alone.  And that is the point - if one has fallen from grace, then there remains no mechanism for salvation at all.  Therefore, one fallen from grace is not saved.

So although Paul is speaking to believing "brethren" here, if they have been deceived and forgotten God's grace (fallen), then they now lose the salvation that God previously gifted them...based on what THEY have done?  Gal 5:7-10 "Ye did run well; who did hinder you that ye should not obey the truth?
8 This persuasion cometh not of him that calleth you.
9 A little leaven leaveneth the whole lump.
10 I have confidence in you through the Lord, that ye will be none otherwise minded: but he that troubleth you shall bear his judgment, whosoever he be."  The "troubler" is the culprit here.

When Paul says the believer is "sealed unto the day of redemption", you disagree then that God's "seal" can actually be broken by man?
